# Vuepress 2 and Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css, vuepress, tailwind-3, vuepress2

I'm trying to use Tailwind CSS with Vuepress 2.
I have installed `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`.

In my `.vuepress/config.js` file I have:

```js
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'

export default {
  title: 'Frontend Library',
  port: 8081,
  ...
  bundlerConfig: {
    viteOptions: {
      css: {
        postcss: {
          plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also `docs/.vuepress/styles/index.scss` file:

```scss
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

There is no error, but Tailwind styles are not applied though..
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you've already got the answer to work through it.

The plugins should be called instead of just put them in the array.

```
bundler: viteBundler({
viteOptions: {
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                autoprefixer(),
                tailwindcss()
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

})

It works for me. Hope it can help you.